# Display specific post on a Wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, post, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to get specific post to display in a single.php page, however for some reason I get all posts displayed. I'm not sure if I am getting post id correctly, but here is how I do it at the moment:

```
    <?php
    $post_id = (int) $_GET['p'];
    query_posts('p=' . $post_id);
    while(have_posts()) 
    { 
        $this_page = the_post();
        echo the_content();
    } 
    ?>
```

It should only display post with one id which is stored in $post_id variable, but for some reason it is getting all of them ;/

Comment: Yes and no - where are you setting the `$id` variable? You would use `get_permalink( 11 );` if you wanted post with an ID of 11.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink#Link_to_Specific_Post

Comment: Ye, the thing is that there could be any id not just 11 in that url, and I need a way to get that Id and than echo it out in a query so I get a post with whatever id is in the url.

Comment: @McNab I changed the question now to show exactly what I'm trying to do (with GET method) So I don't use permalinks now, but for some reason it is still not working ;/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried grabbing the post ID from the URL?

```
<?php
   $post_id = (int) $_GET['p'];
   query_posts('p=' . $post_id);
?>
```

Alternatively, this also might work:

```
<?php get_post($post_id); ?>
```

Comment: This is so weird, I'm still getting all posts despite doing this, I thought it should work ;/ I updated my answer to a new query

Comment: @IlyaKnaup The page you're trying to load this post on - is it a custom template page? If so, can you change the GET parameter to something different (i.e. `?postId=11`). Or is this the existing Wordpress page for a post?

Comment: @IlyaKnaup Also, what happens if you try `get_post($post_id)` instead of `query_posts`?

Comment: It's a single.php page, which is a page that Wordpress uses to display posts, according to my tutorial series. And it is using ?p=... for post id

Answer (score 3):

not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I understand that you want to display a specific page on your single.php

why not use this:

```
<?php 
  $page_id = get_ID_by_slug('my_page_slug');
  $page_data = get_page( $page_id );
?> 

<h2><?php echo $page_data->post_title; ?></h2>
<p><?php echo $page_data->post_content; ?></p>
```

and add this to your **functions.php**

/* get page by slug */

```
function get_ID_by_slug($page_slug) {
  $page = get_page_by_path($page_slug);
  if ($page) {
    return $page->ID;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ugly way:

```
query_posts('p=11');
```

(`query_posts` alters the main query)

The less ugly way:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query('p=11');
while($my_query->have_posts()){
  $my_query->the_post();
  the_content();
}
```

Comment: Ye, the thing is that there could be any id not just 11 in that url, and I need a way to get that Id and than echo it out in a query so I get a post with whatever id is in the url.

Comment: I did that and updated my question to use new code, but for some reason I'm still getting all posts